# New to Stack Exchange, suggestions where to move question?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Why are phone calls into company numbers so groggy and distorted?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58106/why-are-phone-calls-into-company-numbers-so-groggy-and-distorted)

This questions got marked as off-topic. Any suggestions where to ask this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any SE site will be able to properly answer the question, since it's quite subjective (what you consider to be distorted and what you observe may not be what others experience) and open to speculation (since most of us don't know the exact implementation of telephony systems at those specific companies). As was pointed out in a comment, the best chance may be to contact the companies itself.